# Question about making prediction with only two variables

Tags: classification, categorical-encoding

I have a data set with only two variables, student id and book id. I have train and test sets and I will make prediction about what book student will get next time. Should I attach dummy variables to studentid and bookid? And what  ml algorithm can be use for this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably want to model tendencies instead of forced choices.  See http://fharrell.com/post/classification

Comment: Could you make the title of your post more informative?

Answer (score 0):

If you had more information about the users and the books, you could try to predict if a user with certain attributes might like a book with supervised learning. But since you know nothing about the users except for the ID, you could go with collaborative filtering: "users who borrowed this book, also borrowed this".

Also you could calculate something like the most requested books overall and combine this global ranking over the books with the one you got from collaborative filtering.

Comment: I have only info about ID's. I'm thinking about maybe I can get good pred. results with Neural Network. Thank's for your comment

Comment: I doubt that, Sergio. At least for supervised approaches like MLP or deep networks. Using only IDs as a feature, you will only end up learning, what you already know: what books have users borrowed in the past. If you go as you plan, your model will not tell you anything interesting.

Comment: Hi Elmar, I have solved the problem. I have used this method.                                   https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/04/guide-sequence-prediction-using-compact-prediction-tree-python/       https://github.com/analyticsvidhya/CPT